# Slider module doesn't work

Tags: slider

I have an issue with my slider module, hope anyone can help.
Slider does not work in Chrome 45.0.2454.101 nor in Microsoft Edge, this module: https://addons.prestashop.com/en/sliders-galleries/26873-multi-layer-slider-pro-visual-drag-drop-slider.html 
I can't drag the object and the console does not output any error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test with Microsoft edge, but it seems to be working for me in the version of Chrome that you mentioned [GitHub](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3454081/10145868/5538529c-65eb-11e5-8f76-ecba0a8f4b51.gif)
Could you double check by navigating to the documentation site on Chrome?